# Want to add multiple values in "NOT Like" in where condition in sql

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a query in which I want to check for multiple values which should not be in where clause. I want to exclude those records which have those values

```
Select * from Order where order_number NOT LIKE ('%asd%','%ass%','%asdd%')
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess you'll have to go with a typical `AND`:

```
Select * from Order where 
         order_number NOT LIKE '%asd%'
     AND order_number NOT LIKE '%ass%'
     AND order_number NOT LIKE '%asdd%'
```